# Android @Inject and @InjectView annotations meaning

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, annotations

Whats the **meaning** and **purpose** of `@Inject` *and / or* `@InjectView` annotations in Android / Java programming?

How can I use it?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: I know that people use these with Butterknife, in order to set layouts with fewer lines of code than is normally required:  https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Comment: Yes, I came across this annotations, and there are so many libraries which use it, but I don't know how to and the purpose.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Android, these annotations are part of the [Roboguice framework](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice). They are used to provide [dependency injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) in an Android environment.

This allows you to directly inject an instance of the desired resource, whether it's a basic POJO, a view, or another resource. Here's a POJO example from the [RoboGuice wiki](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki):

```
class MyActivity extends RoboActivity {
    @Inject Foo foo; // this will basically call new Foo();
}
```

This is a trivial one, but essentially the injection point is allowing your class to stay independent of creating/managing an instance of the injected Foo class and instead puts that responsibility on Foo itself by calling Foo's default constructor in this case. This allows for easier testing via something like mocks since MyActivity is free from the details of actual creating Foo itself.

Comment: Ok, but what is the purpose of the @Inject annotation?

Comment: Added a little bit to the answer. It doesn't go in-depth at all, but hopefully the links provide some guidance.

Comment: I have a class that `extends RoboActivity`, as you mentioned, and it uses the @Inject like this:

    @Inject
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    @Inject
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

Why is it useful to inject SharedPreferences, for example?
And how is it able to `get` values from the `prefs` without construct or set it  before?